# Workflow Foundation 4 - Showing Workflow Progress

Tags: c#, .net, workflow-foundation, workflow-foundation-4

In a project that we are using WF4, it is a requirement to show our users a friendly list of the steps of the workflow (the logical steps from the users point of view, not the technical steps) along with each step's status ( like a big green check mark if the step has been completed).

I'm wondering if this is something that Workflow tracking should be used for or not. My impression from what I have read about workflow tracking is that it is really more for technical logging.

The alternatives would be persisting an ordered list of steps and their statuses along with the workflow or outside of the workflow.

Either way I'm fuzzy about how this should work and appreciate suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Workflow Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164251.aspx) would be very useful for you. This is some sort of convergence point between wf and wcf and used to marshal WCF services calls to WF instances. You can create a duplex channel and receive updates via callback channel.

Comment: I'm using workflow services, but I'm not sure that you understand what I'm asking. Your suggestions sounds like I'd have the ability to show status updates in real-time, which isn't really a requirement. I just need the user to lookup a workflow they are interested in and check to see where it is at.

Comment: Got it... sorry

I had a similar problem and I've solved it by the following way. I had an object, the responsibility of which was to store the state of workflow. This object was persisted in DB and updated by WF.

Answer (score 0):

You can use workflow tracking to register activity execution and use the WorkflowDesigner to show the progress to the user. There is an example of how to do this in the WF4 samples from Microsoft you can find [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd483375%28VS.100%29.aspx).

Comment: I can't use the workflow designer. The client is a Silverlight application.

Comment: You can use the WorkflowDesigner to generate an image and display that in a Silverlight client. If not you have to build a view from scratch based on the tracking information.

Comment: Do you know where that example is specifically?

Comment: Not sure if there is a good sample to do that but the question has come up several times and has been answered by Tim Lovell-Smith is I am not mistaken.